# Is it possible to automatically update datetime for modify_on for any changes in table except few columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

ALTER TABLE app_user
add column modifyon datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

It works but for all columns and I want to exclude few column such as lastlogin, InvalidTryCount  etc.

eg. if have 4 column a, b, c, d  I want modify_on to work for a and b column  but if there are any changes in c or d it should not automatically add timestamp in modify_on

Comment: Don’t think so, you might want to consider two tables or managing modifyon within your application code/logic

Comment: Consider a trigger instead.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by _"It works but for all columns"_ ? As far as I can see (from your question) you only added one column `modifyon` with `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` clause. Probably it's better if you run `SHOW CREATE TABLE app_user` and post [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70781961/edit).